# How to fix delayed data on prepare segue?

Tags: swift, prepared-statement, segue

My data got delayed 1 time when I want to pass the data in my tableview and pass it to another viewcontroller

i'm using prepare for segue.

now, in order to get the right data i need go back to the table view and press the same row

```swift
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "toRequestCorrection"{
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! RequestCorrectionViewController
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
                destinationVC.Shift = self.correction["Shift"].stringValue
                destinationVC.LogDate = self.correction["LogDate"].stringValue
                destinationVC.logIn = self.correction["ActualLogIn"].stringValue
                destinationVC.logOut = self.correction["ActualLogOut"].stringValue
                destinationVC.breakEnd = self.correction["ActualBreakEnd"].stringValue
                destinationVC.breakStart = self.correction["ActualBreakStart"].stringValue
                destinationVC.overTimeIn = self.correction["ActualOverTimeIn"].stringValue
                destinationVC.overTimeOut = self.correction["ActualOverTimeOut"].stringValue
                destinationVC.transactionStatusID = self.correction["TransactionStatusID"].intValue
            }
        }
    }
```

it's should pass the data on the row right after i pressed the row

Comment: It looks like the popular well-liked *asynchronous trap*

Comment: @vadian isee, so where i should put the asynchronus in order to send the right data?

Comment: Connect the segue to the view controller, get the data in `didSelect` and call `performSegue` *manually* in the completion block.

Comment: can you give the example? @vadian

Comment: My last comment **is** an example. It's pretty straightforward. To provide a concrete solution the code in the question is too vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additionally, you do not have to use segue, you can instantiate your view controller inside didSelectRowAt method with following code without prepareForSegue.

EDIT: You didn't indicate it's an async task. So, I am using Alamofire with completion handler. I think it will be useful for you.

```
typealias yourCompletionHandler = (Data?, _ message: String?, _ errorStatusCode: Int?) -> Void
func yourAsyncTask(handler: @escaping yourCompletionHandler) {
    let parameters: [String: Any] = ["unitId": 4124]
    let url = ""
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters)
        .responseObject { (response: DataResponse<BaseListResponseParser<YourModel>>) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                if let result = response.result.value {
                  handler(result.listItems, nil, nil)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
    }
} 


yourAsyncTask { [weak self] (yourModel, error, _) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let destination = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerId") as? RequestCorrectionViewController else { return }
            destination.Shift = yourModel.shift
            navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Using that way you do not need to create segue or prepareForSegue method.

Comment: Actually this doesn't help because there is an asynchronous task involved.

Comment: thankyou for the answer @AtalayAsa, i think i know why my data is not passed in the first time, because i'm using Alamofire to get the data before prepare my segue, but actually the system run the segue first then run the alamofire, that's why my data got delayed. 

My problem now is i don't understand where i should put DispatchQueue.main.async {} in order to run the alamofire before the segue run

Comment: You're welcome @KlaudiusIvan. Actually, you should use DispatchQueue.main.async when you need to make UI related things. If we come back your question that's why I put completion handler. When your server request is done handler is triggered immediately, then the code inside DispatchQueue.main.async invokes and it is the place where you put your segue code.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `tableVew(_:willSelectRowAt:)` method of `UITableViewDelegate` in your viewController and set your correction property to selected row's value.

```
class YourSourceViewController: UITableViewDelegate{
    var correction: Correction!

    func tableView(_ tabelView: UITableView, willSelecRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath?{
        correction = correctionList[indexPath.row]
        return indexPath
    }

    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryBoardSegue, sender: Any?){
        //passing data to RequestCorrectionViewController.
        //And also you don't need to check if indexPath is nil.
        //Because this block will called only any row of tableView is selected.
    }
}
```

Also note that you could do same thing in `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` method but this method works after performing segues and cause the problem you are encountered too.

**Edit**

If you think using `willSelectRowAt:` method is a misusing, you can set your segue's source your viewController (instead of template cell) and set identifier on Storyboard and call it programmatically. like @vadian's said

```
func tableView(_ tabelView: UITableView, didSelecRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        correction = correctionList[indexPath.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier "mySegueIdentifier", sender: self)
    }
```

Comment: Actually this doesn't help because there is an asynchronous task involved. And you are misusing `willSelectRowAt`.

Comment: If you mean performing segue by asynchronous task, this operation will be performed after `willSelect` method. Also If you return nil in willSelectRow method, segue will not be performed.

About misusing, I am not sure about that. It could be a choice accourding to usage in whole of application.

Comment: thank you for the answer, I'm working on your answer but I don't know what is correction:Correction!

Comment: It is the instance that you pass in `prepare(for:sender:)` method.

I make up `Correction` type as your model type. I guess you used `Dictionary` there instead of a class model.